# Group Homomorphism and injective

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a group homomorphism $\psi:A_8\rightarrow S_9$  for which there exists $\alpha\in A_8$   with $\psi(\alpha)=(1\, 2)$, prove that $\psi$  is injective.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the following fact. If $\psi:G\to H$ is a group homomorphism and $G$ is a simple group, then $\psi$ is either injective or $\psi(g)=e$ for all $g\in G$.

Now in your case, the group $A_8$ is simple, so you can apply the above result (which you may wish to prove for yourself). Now ask yourself, for the given $\psi$, is it true that $\psi(g)=e$ for all $g\in A_8$? Your answer to that, in combination with the above mentioned result, will give you the conclusion you want.

Assuming this is homework, you will need to properly justify your answer by quoting relevant theorems.