# Given a group homomorphism $\psi$ from A8 to S9 prove that $\psi$ is injective

Tags: proof-verification, abstract-algebra

[image]

Given a group homomorphism $\psi$ from A8 to S9

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997562/group-homomorphism-and-injective.